# Different IP for same FQDN using different resolver

Tags: domain-name-system, ip, dns-zone, dig

For my domain `gobudgie.ml` I get different IPs on different DNS resolver eg.:

```
jasmich.ml@8.8.4.4 (Default):

jasmich.ml.     964 IN  A   31.17.211.88

jasmich.ml@1.1.1.1 (CloudFlare):

jasmich.ml.     966 IN  A   31.17.210.230
```

(https://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=jasmich.ml&type=&useresolver=8.8.4.4&ns=all&nameservers=)

The DNS record was last updated some month ago, so it's probably not a problem of the TTL.

Might this be a problem with the DNSEC?

The actual IP address is `31.17.211.88`

Answer (score 1):

That's because the data at your registry's DNS servers is not in sync:

```
vesemir:~> dig @ns01.freenom.com. jasmich.ml a +short
31.17.211.88
vesemir:~> dig @ns02.freenom.com. jasmich.ml a +short
31.17.211.88
vesemir:~> dig @ns03.freenom.com. jasmich.ml a +short
31.17.211.88
vesemir:~> dig @ns04.freenom.com. jasmich.ml a +short
31.17.210.230
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and:

```
vesemir:~> dig @ns01.freenom.com. jasmich.ml soa +short
soa.freenom.com. ns01.freenom.com. 1567699048 10800 3600 604800 2560
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
vesemir:~> dig @ns04.freenom.com. jasmich.ml soa +short
soa.freenom.com. ns01.freenom.com. 1530981232 10800 3600 604800 2560
                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Please raise this issue with freenom.

Comment: What does this number `1530981232` mean?

Comment: It's the UNIX Epoch time for `GMT: Thu, Sep 5, 2019 6:13:55 PM`. This serial format is common on DNSSEC signed zones; it's the time when the zone was signed.

Comment: contact your DNS provider, one dns server is out of sync.